# How can I find the number of businesses in a certain radius?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Given the following:

- Coordinates of a certain place
- Radius in meters
- A business category, aka "supported place type" (like "art_gallery")

I can get details of all (limited by 20) art galleries in that given area, by calling:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=51.4918296,-0.1926405&radius=1000&types=art_gallery&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY
```

Since the use of this API is limited to 20 results (lately paging is possible, but it's slow and limited as well), questions like "What's the number of restaurants in a two mile radius?" are not practical.

Note: I don't need the details of the businesses - just the total number.

**Is there an alternative to the API mentioned? using Google API or others?**

---

As I get no answers (perhaps because there isn't an answer other than "No"), here is an alternative question:

**Is there an API that can supply a static map image, showing all businesses of a certain type in a certain area?** i.e. for *"Interior Design shops in Hampstead, London"* show me:

[image]

I know there's [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), but I couldn't find any integration with Google Places API.

Comment: Just to confirm, It is not possible with Google APIs, not sure about alternatives.

Comment: Returning total number of listings sounds like a good feature, please submit a [Places API Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) for this.

Comment: Submitted a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4352&thanks=4352&ts=1344841870). Follow link and vote please...

Comment: do you have any idea regarding http://stackoverflow.com/q/12024394/582571

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use Google Maps Image APIs for part of your question?

IE:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=400x150&sensor=false&types=art_gallery">
```

for

[image]

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I know there's Google Static Maps API, but I couldn't find any integration with Google Places API, So it is not enough. Thanks for the answer though...

Comment: Ah my mistake, I overlooked your last statement. Best of luck!