# Search all places in given city name

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Right now i am using Google Places API for fetching Restaurant list in particular city, query like

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

But the problem here is that we can only have 20 result and with help of **`next_page_token`** in the response we can again fetch 20 more, by this we can only have 60 result.

> [Mention on Google Places API page](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchResponses)
>
> The maximum number of results that
>   can be returned is 60

**So is there any other authentic way to fetch all the Restaurant details.**

Just for information : I am implementing this in android application.

Comment: +1 for your answer, this will be good alternative, but i think zomato's have indian city's database. So the application will be only usable in india, not the universal :(

Comment: you really don't have much of an option; use zomato for Indian cities + Places for elsewhere - then again you might run into another city which isn't covered by either of these services. You're pretty much at the mercy of others, if you don't have your own database

Comment: There is no way to fetch all restaurants using the Google Places API. What is your usecase for this?

Comment: Hi chris , i want the restaurant list by providing city name, so i found a way on Google places API but with limited result. Is there other authentic way for fetching restaurant results using google map ??

Comment: I just have a city name , and based on that i have to fetch list of restaurant for that city only. and as of restaurant we can also find other things like bank, institute.... etc

Answer (score 1):

Searches are performed by looking within a radius of a given set of coordinates (you can't search just by city name).  The maximum search radius is 50km.  If there's more than 60 results in that area, you could reduce your search radius, then [split up the query into multiple calls](https://gist.github.com/flibbertigibbet/7956133).  I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to have the user fetch that much data on a mobile device all at once, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a different location api like MapQuest's or Bing's? As far as I know MapQuest does not have a transactional limit for the community license (open data). I don't think there's a limit to the number of results returned other than the ones you impose in your query.

Comment: something like this
http: //open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=restaurants+sydney

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in MapQuest query result is very less, i tried http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=restaurants+ahmedabad for "Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India" but didn't get proper restaurant result